# Add spacing to Twitter Bootstrap submenu

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am trying to add some spacing to the left of the Twitter Bootstrap submenu so there is a bit of spacing between the 2nd and 3rd level menus. So, I've used the following added CSS:

```
.dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu {
    margin: -1px 0 0 5px;
}
```

But, when the user moves the mouse over the gap, the submenu disappears (go slow). How can I add the space and keep the menu showing while mousing over to it?

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/trxk8/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really the prettiest of solutions but you could pad out the `.dropdown-submenu` elements with a transparent 5px border.

A side effect of this would be that you would also have to trim down the child anchor tag a little bit:

**CSS**

```
.dropdown-submenu  {
    border-right: transparent block 5px;
    margin-right: -5px;
}

.dropdown-submenu > a {
    position: relative;
    right: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/trxk8/8/**

Note, you would still be keeping `margin-top: -1px` in `.dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu`

Comment: Close enough for me :) Only problem I see is the top left corner not being rounded, but thats not too big a deal. Thanks!

Comment: @David the top left corner not being rounded is a bootstrap css feature (line 2996 in `.dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu`). You can overide this in your own css using `.dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu { border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px; }`